# Reporting Services 2008 & 2012 side by side

Tags: ssrs

I have installed Sql Server 2008 & 2012 side by side on the same machine, and that's includes the reporting service for each. Both are instances are named instances: MSSQLSERVER2008 and MSSQLSERVER2012.

I didn't configure the 2008 one but configured 2012 first and this one is working fine. However later on when I wanted to configure the 2008 reporting service instance I was not able to do so; it simply cannot find it.
Both services are displayed as running, nevertheless while being in Reporting Services Configuration Manager only the 2012 instance is displayed.

I tried stopping the 2012 but still no luck, 2008 won't show up in the RS configuration manager.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

IIRC RS Configuration Manager looks for matching version of the report server. You will need RSConfigTool that comes with Sql Server 2008 (you can run it remotely on any other machine)

Answer (score 0):

@lev
You are right and I did try to config both of the Reporting Services using the appropriate configuration manager but for some reason the 2008 didn't show up.
What I ended up doing was:
- uninstall the RS2012 (only this feature)
- at this point I was able to go into RSCM2008 and configure the reporting service 2008
- re-install the reporting service 2012 and re-configure it.
It didn't take too long, about 1 hour, but at least I stopped wondering what was wrong before.
Your suggestion is correct; I would vote it up but I don't have the reputation :-).
Thanks for taking the time and answer.
Iulian